# How can we add a field to a data frame, from another data frame, when the sizes/indexes are different?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I'm stumped on this one.  I have two data frames that are completely different, but I want to add a field from one to the other.  I tried the following.

```
grouped_and_summed['schedule_code'] = df['schedule_code']
```

It's giving me all NAN under `grouped_and_summed['schedule_code']`

I tried `pd.concat`.  That didn't work, because these two data frames have nothing in common.  All I want to do is take a value, which has been parsed correctly in `df['schedule_code']` and insert it into `grouped_and_summed['schedule_code']`.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it correctly, concat should do the work if you set correctly the axis:

```
pd.concat([grouped_and_summed, df['schedule_code']], ignore_index=True, axis=1)
```

Comment: No, pd.concat doesn't work.  I just tried it again.  I got this error: ValueError: Shape of passed values is (35905187, 74), indices imply (531981, 74)

There must be another way of doing this kind of thing.

Comment: It could be due to the fact that there are duplicated indexes. What if you try `grouped_and_summed.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`, `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)` and **then** using pd.concat?